# Covid Vaccination Proof needed for Domestic Travel in the US

Tags: covid-19, domestic-travel

Is covid vaccination proof needed for domestic travel within the US? I have a photo of my card as well as the actual card itself. If proof of vaccination is needed, which one should I show?

Answer (score 3):

Domestic travel within the US does not require you to be vaccinated, and thus does not require any proof of vaccination.